# Calling net use works manually but not in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, net-use

Calling

```
net use F: \\my\destination\folder /user:myuser password
```

works fine.

When in a Batch file, it says "System error 86" ( = wrong password)

How can this be ? Is the batch file somehow encoded differently ?

Comment: I only guessing. Your password contains a percent sign, in a batch file you need to double it, `my%pwd` becomes `my%%pwd`

Comment: Another question, why do you need this? Couldn't you use `/persistent` then you don't need to store your password in a batch file at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

did the trick

The password contained a "!" and somehow had to be escaped.

The weird thing is that during this hour of desperate testing, we came across some strange effects that were probably caused by windows caching network passwords (at least we came to this conclusion)